# Is there something similar to "open with" in nautilus for midnight commander?

Tags: 14.04, midnight-commander

I want to have choose among software when I press Enter button in Midnight Commander (MC).
For example, sometimes I open txt files with gedit or GVim.
HTML files I can open with firefox or with GVim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `user menu` (Command > User menu [F2]) to have several actions assigned to one file type. And to customise it - `Command > Edit menu file`.

Answer (score 0):

Preferred application name can be typed on command line and the selected file name can be copied after the application name by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or sequence <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.